# Azure Service Bus metadata as Dependecy Properties in Application Insights

Tags: azure-application-insights, azureservicebus

I have this webservice that recieves data from an external party. This data will be posted on Azure ServiceBus. The data contains an unique ID that I would like to log my distributed tracing in Application Insights.
This is possible by using `telemetryClient.StartOperation` and populating the `Properties` dictionary. This creates a new line in the end-to-end transaction details that I would like to avoid.

It is possible to create an `ITelemetryInitializer` that has a dependency on `IHttpContextAccessor` and use that to add properties to the telemetry based on a webrequest.

My question is: can I do the same thing when a message is put on the ServiceBus? Or is there a way to add data to the current `ITelemetry` context?

Comment: Can you provide the code that which you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: can I do the same thing when a message is put on the ServiceBus? Or is there a way to add data to the current `ITelemetry` context?

There's no direct equivalent of an `IHttpContextAccessor` for Service Bus messages, but we can achieve by using Application Insights telemetry and custom telemetry initializers.

- Created a new class `ServiceBusTelemetryInitializer` in the folder within your project folder. This class should implement the `ITelemetryInitializer` interface.

**Telemetry Initializer:**

```cs
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

public class ServiceBusTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public ServiceBusTelemetryInitializer(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        var context = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
        if (context != null && context.Items.ContainsKey("ServiceBusData"))
        {
            var serviceBusData = context.Items["ServiceBusData"] as YourServiceBusDataClass;
            telemetry.Context.Properties["ServiceBusUniqueId"] = serviceBusData.UniqueId.ToString();
            // Add other relevant properties
        }
    }
}
```

- In `Startup.cs` Configure Services method, I added the necessary configuration to register the telemetry initializer. This involves adding the `IHttpContextAccessor` dependency and configuring Application Insights.

Here Iam able to get the messageID that you can see below:

[image]

Below we can see the message process custom event data:

[image]

**In-Detail:**
[image]

Comment: I literally mentioned that option in my question. What I asked for was something similar for a ServiceBus context.